# Marketing cloud - transactional journey - how to use attributes in email

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, transactional-messaging-api

I created my first transactional journey and it send a text email and very fast after injecting it via postman.
Now when I try to pass attributes to use them, I get an error and I am not able to change my new email.

I added this UserAttribute_1 in my email %%UserAttribute_1%%, this way:

"Hello, your %%UserAttribute_1%%
thanks"

and then I plan to use it in postman adding

```
...
"attributes": {
 "UserAttribute_1":"myname",
...
```

when I go to my transactional journey and want to change it, I am getting this popup error:

```
Error saving activity
Changes to the triggered send message were saved. The triggered send was paused but could not be published.
```

Am I missing anything?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Did you add this as a field in the TriggeredSend DataExtension or as a profile attribute?

Most likely the TriggeredSend is failing validation for this issue.

Comment: no I didnt, where should I add it, as new fields in my data extension?

Comment: It is a bit hard to read if you do not know the abbreviations ;)